# Teste de unidade com o banco de dados

Tags: java, hsqldb, junit, testes-de-unidade

Tenho uma aplicação que usa JPA 2 com o Hibernate por trás e para os testes de unidade, eu utilizo o HSQLDB em memória com o JUnit 4.11. O HSQLDB é configurado em um arquivo persistence.xml em uma pasta META-INF.

A minha pergunta é: Como faço para subir o banco de dados limpo no início de cada teste sem ter que manualmente chamar um monte de "DELETE FROM BLABLA" ou coisa semelhante?

Atualmente eu tenho problemas dentro dos métodos `@Before`, uma chamada mais ou menos assim:

```java
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
```

Os `EntityManager`s produzidos são colocados em uma variável `ThreadLocal`, de forma a garantir que cada thread não manipule os `EntityManager`s de outras threads.

Nos métodos `@After` eu chamo um `entityManager.clear()`.

Entretanto, o teste não está confiável. Algumas vezes objetos salvos desaparecem sem motivo aparente. E frequentemente a cache do Hibernate me engana mostrando objetos que não estão persistidos, mas parecem que estão, e com isso eu acabo abusando do uso de `entityManager.clear()` por precaução em lugares aonde isso não deveria ser necessário.

Alguém tem uma sugestão melhor de alguma estratégia para desenvolver testes utilizando o HSQLDB em memória com o JUnit?

Comment: Sem querer ser chato, mas já sendo: se está acessando um banco de dados (mesmo que seja em memória), não é teste de unidade -- é teste de integração. Tendo dito isso, tive sucesso no passado usando [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) para esses testes, executando [operações apropriadas](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/operation/DatabaseOperation.html) nos métodos setUp/tearDown.

Comment: @elias , o fato de ser ou não ser um teste unitário por acessar um banco em memória é discutível (e tem sido discutido por anos). Um dos contra-argumentos é que tudo deveria então ser chamado de teste de integração, já que você depende do bom funcionamento do sistema operacional, ou do Java em si. Em suma, eu não mudaria a tecnologia para me adequar ao nome. Eu mudaria o nome, para adequar à tecnologia. Eu vejo muito mais valia em se testar com os itens reais, do que introduzir o DbUnit só para que possa chamar meus testes de "testes unitários" :-)

Comment: @jpkrohling a sugestão de introduzir o DbUnit foi pra resolver o problema do OP, os testes ainda continuariam sendo testes de integração. =) O contra-argumento que "tudo deveria ser chamado de teste de integração" é inválido, porque a diferença entre os testes não é simplesmente do que ele depende pra funcionar e sim dos objetivos dos testes. Testes de unidade objetivam: 1) ter feedback rápido, 2) chegar num bom design através de se colocar no lugar do usuário, e 3) reduzir o nosso medo na hora de fazer alterações.

Comment: @jpkrohling Para fazer testes unitários no caso apresentado, o trabalho provavelmente envolveria criar uma nova suíte de testes, usando mocks/stubs para os colaboradores, a fim de isolar apenas o código escrito na unidade real (não testar o código das bibliotecas e frameworks, por exemplo), e assim ter o feedback rápido desejado (tipo, >1s não é rápido). =) Leitura recomendada: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/test-driven-traps-part-1.html

Comment: @elias, estou bem ciente da definição dos testes unitários, mas acho que a definição muitas vezes é levada muito ao pé da letra. O ponto principal é que apenas uma unidade do seu código seja testada, independente do número de coisas que acontecem por trás deste seu código. Se uma linha do meu código chama 1.000 linhas do Hibernate, então eu certamente quero testar minha integração com o Hibernate, já que uma mudança de versão pode me afetar. Mesma coisa com a JVM, ou com chamadas nativas. Existem casos, claro, em que é desejado testar apenas a sua lógica, como em algoritmos complexos.

Comment: Em tempo, acredito que nenhum dos itens mencionados sejam determinantes para classificar os testes do OP como unitários ou de integração: com DB em memória, eles dão um feedback rápido, encorajam um bom design (os testes são os primeiros consumidores do código), e certamente reduzem o medo na hora das alterações :-)

Comment: @elias Creio que tudo depende do objetivo do teste. Se estamos testando um componente específico para assegurar seu bom funcionamento, ainda que esse componente resida numa "bolha" (o banco é "fake", as entradas são fake, etc), então estamos fazendo um teste de unidade. Se assumimos que dois ou mais componentes funcionam como deveriam (por exemplo, após fazer testes de unidade em cada um deles separadamente) e queremos ver se eles interagem corretamente entre si, então temos testes de integração. O tempo de resposta não tem nada a ver com isso (ainda que na prática desejemos feedback rápido).

Comment: @jpkrohling sem me extender (mesmo porque os comentários não são o lugar certo pra esse tipo de discussão), creio que no seu exemplo a linha que faz interface com o hibernate pode ser testada (unit) usando entradas e saídas falsas que correspondam ao que você espera do hibernate. Mas no momento em que você está interessado em como o seu componente **interage** com versões específicas do hibernate, então o que você está testando é a integração entre os dois sistemas.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, verdade, essa discussão vai longe (é um dos tópicos mais discutidos no mundo dos testes). O fato é que o objetivo do teste não é testar a integração com o Hibernate, mas o teste certamente vai falhar quando algo no Hibernate mudar. E isso é uma coisa boa.

Comment: Desculpe se estou sendo repetindo algo que já pode ser entendido pelos comentários anteriores, mas só para reforçar, quando um teste pode influenciar em outro (seja pela sequência de execução ou devido à concorrência) então o conceito de *teste unitário* é ameaçado e problemas como este vão surgir. Citando a resposta do @MarcosZolnowski, deve haver uma nova instância do banco para cada teste.

Comment: O tempo de resposta é bem significativo no prazo médio, porque a consequência de uma suíte de testes lenta é deixar de rodá-la, e a consequência disso frequentemente é deixar de escrever testes. Tô falando aqui, mas *been there, done that* -- sou o primeiro culpado de fazer a mesma coisa, muitas vezes. =) Talvez isso seja mesmo uma questão de opinião de acordo com a experiência.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem um `EntityManager` por thread, mas todos compartilham o mesmo banco. Se você executa os testes concorrentemente, o que um teste faz, pode afetar os outros testes.

É necessário criar o banco em memória a cada teste.

Vou citar um [tutorial](http://vageeshhoskere.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/unit-test-with-junit-for-hibernate-using-hsqldb-in-memory/).
Aonde ele cria um arquivo **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;shutdown=false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property><!-- default username -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/><!-- default password -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property><!-- creates the tables from the entites automatically -->
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
  <mapping class="blog.hibernate.employee.Employee"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

E coloca no `@BeforeClass` do teste:

```java
    @BeforeClass
    public void init() {
        config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        config.configure(new File("hibernate.cfg.xml"));
            factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
            hibernateSession = factory.openSession();
        }
```

É um tutorial um pouco antigo, mas deve ser bem próximo do que você precisa fazer nessa versão do Hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma propriedade do Hibernate que se chama `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`. Quando está em `create-drop`, vai apagar tudo e recriar do zero, situação ideal para seus testes. O que eu costumo fazer é ter uma classe base que se encarrega de recriar o banco de dados a cada teste. Repare que isso acontece com cada método de teste, fazendo que a execução de seus testes fique lenta, mas é um preço que acho justo pagar. Uma boa fonte de referência é a suíte de testes do próprio Hibernate. Eles usam uma saída diferente, que é a de recriar o banco de dados a cada classe. Para tal, usam algumas extensões do JUnit, que talvez seja demais para o caso normal.

Aqui vão alguns exemplos que uso em projetos pessoais, que talvez possam servir de inspiração:

[META-INF/persistence.xml](https://bitbucket.org/jpkroehling/cascaio/src/0bcf8673429135bd7dec18edcbd616b4096716f7/backend/src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml), com nada de mais, exceto a propriedade que apaga e recria o banco de dados.

[TestWithEntityManager](https://bitbucket.org/jpkroehling/cascaio/src/0bcf8673429135bd7dec18edcbd616b4096716f7/backend/src/test/java/com/cascaio/backend/v1/boundary/referencedata/TestWithEntityManager.java), classe base para os testes que necessitam de banco de dados.

[CategoryServiceTest](https://bitbucket.org/jpkroehling/cascaio/src/0bcf8673429135bd7dec18edcbd616b4096716f7/backend/src/test/java/com/cascaio/backend/v1/boundary/referencedata/CategoryServiceTest.java), exemplo de uma classe que utiliza o TestWithEntityManager.

Answer (score 1):

Como já mencionado em outras respostas, o Hibernate é capaz de criar a estrutura do banco de dados com o ajuste da propriedade `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.

Entretanto, o uso deste recurso é inviável em cenários um pouco mais complexos onde, por exemplo, existe um DBA no processo. Há muitas outras questões nesse aspecto, pois muitas vezes necessitamos de ajustes finos no banco: criação de índices, estruturas específicas de um SGBDR, cargas de dados.

Soluções para isso vieram na especificação JPA 2.1 deste ano, que permitem que scripts SQL sejam executados antes ou depois da cosntrução do *metadata* do banco de dados, ou ainda somente os scripts sejam executados. Veja [alguns](http://www.mastertheboss.com/quickstart-tutorials-hibernate/jpa/jpa-21-tutorial) [artigos](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_schema_generation) [sobre](http://hantsy.blogspot.de/2013/12/jpa-21-schema-generation-properties.html) o assunto. Então seria possível definir um script para criar a estrutura necessária do banco de dados no início de cada teste.

Outra abordagem para criar um "frankenstein" que mistura teste unitário e de integração (não quero entrar aqui na discussão do que é o que) é usar um framework de testes que permita alguns ajustes a mais, como o [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html). Este possui uma API muito similar ao JUnit, mas com alguns recursos a mais:

- Especificar dependência entre testes ou grupo de testes (influencia na ordem de execução)
- Especificar testes que podem ou não ser executados em paralelo
- Testes parametrizados com um [Data Provider](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/)

(Para comparações entre JUnit e TestNG ver [estes](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-vs-testng-comparison/) [links](http://scrtchpad.wordpress.com/2011/08/07/testng-or-junit/).)

Enfim, fiz uma breve apresentação sobre o TestNG porque ele permite criar algo que fica entre um teste unitário e um de integração através dos agrupamentos de testes e da dependência entre eles.

Para exemplificar, alguém poderia criar um teste `@Test processarContratos()` que dependesse do teste `@Test incluirCliente()` (que inclui um cliente) e do teste `@TestincluirContrato(Contrato c)` (que está ligado a um DataProvider e incluir diversos contratos). Métodos anotados com `@BeforeSuite` e `@AfterSuite` podem ser usados para inicializar e encerrar os recursos necessários para os métodos de uma *Test Suit*.